# mat-checkbox inside cdkList not visually changing the checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm using angular v16 along with angular material and I'm trying to create a custom component which uses the cdkListbox with a child mat-checkbox but when I'm selecting the option within the listbox it does not visually change the checkbox but it does change the selected model value which it is bound to.

If the checkbox is updated outside of the cdkList then it does toggle the checkbox. Below is a basic example of my issue and I've used the example from the cdk documentation.

If you toggle the first option "Sprigatito" you will see that it does toggle the second option "Sprigatito" as well as updating the selected value in the json.

If you toggle the second option "Sprigatito" you will see that it does toggle both checkboxes as expected as well as the json.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ax5jwo

template.html

```
    <div class="example-listbox-container">
  <label class="example-listbox-label" id="example-starter-pokemon-label">
    Starter Pokemon
  </label>
  {{ starters | json }}
  <ul
    cdkListbox
    [cdkListboxValue]="starter"
    (cdkListboxValueChange)="starter = $event.value;"
    aria-labelledby="example-starter-pokemon-label"
    class="example-listbox"
  >
    <li
      *ngFor="let pokemon of starters"
      [cdkOption]="pokemon"
      class="example-option"
    >
      <mat-checkbox  [(ngModel)]="pokemon.selected"> {{pokemon.name}} </mat-checkbox>
      
    </li>
  </ul>

  Toggling the below checkboxes changes the visual state of the above checkboxes
 <ul>
  <li><mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="starters[0].selected"> {{starters[0].name}} </mat-checkbox></li>
  <li><mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="starters[1].selected"> {{starters[1].name}} </mat-checkbox></li>
    <li><mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="starters[2].selected"> {{starters[2].name}} </mat-checkbox></li>
 </ul>

</div>
<p>
  Your starter pokemon is <strong>{{starter | json}}</strong>&nbsp;
</p>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgFor, JsonPipe, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CdkListbox, CdkOption } from '@angular/cdk/listbox';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

interface PokemonModel {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  selected: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-listbox-value-binding-example',
  exportAs: 'cdkListboxValueBindingExample',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-listbox-value-binding-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-listbox-value-binding-example.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CdkListbox,
    NgFor,
    CdkOption,
    JsonPipe,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class CdkListboxValueBindingExample {
  starters: PokemonModel[] = [
    { id: '1', name: 'Sprigatito', selected: false },
    { id: '2', name: 'Fuecoco', selected: false },
    { id: '3', name: 'Quaxly', selected: false },
  ];
  starter: readonly PokemonModel[] = [];
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "example-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "16.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "16.1.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "16.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Very cool stackblitz, ty ! I suspect the cdkListbox to catch the mouse-click event, so the mat-checkbox is confused. Actually, your cdkListbox allows you to select a line, and the checkbox too, so you have 2 machanics to select a pokemon at the same place, which are in conflit. You should chose one or the other...

Comment: To disable the list selection, add `[cdkListboxDisabled]="true"`. If you want to enable the list selection, but disable the checkbox, it may be more complex...

Comment: @Random your suggestion does fix the issue in the stackblitz but it doesn't fix it in my real world scenario so I'll try to update the stackblitz to closer match. In my real example I have built a component library which uses reactive forms and the ControlValueAccessor and it allows the option to select multiple. I suspect the root issue is the same I just can't get it to work.

Comment: can you use something else than cdkListbox ? This component is made to be selectable, and this is not what you wish, so there may be simpler component (or even a simple div with an *ngFor...) ?

Comment: @Random If you add a comment as an answer about setting [cdkListboxDisabled]="true" I will mark it as an answer as I have removed the cdkListbox now and have it working but your original comment did fix the question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the `cdkListbox` to catch the mouse-click event, so the `mat-checkbox` is confused. Actually, your `cdkListbox` allows you to select a line, and the checkbox too, so you have 2 mechanics to select an item at the same place.

The quickest fix is to disable the list selection, adding `[cdkListboxDisabled]="true"`.

The better solution would be not to use `cdkListbox`, and use a component which does not handle selection. Even a div with an `*ngFor` could be enough depending your needs.